# How to filter report from google analytics v4 with many optional strings in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-analytics-api

The dimension I use is `ga:pagePathLevel2` because inside path level I have article ID that I couple with the rest of the data from the database.

Example: `/lifestyle/40846-scenic-eclipse`

lets say I have ids 
`ids = [23692, 23693, 23964, 23965, 23966]`

Now I would like to create a filter, that will return report only for those pages, that have this ids in their `pagePathLevel2` String.

Any help?

Thank you

The rest of the object

```
{
        'reportRequests': [
            {
                'viewId': VIEW_ID,
                'dateRanges': [
                    {'startDate': current_dt.strftime(date_format), 'endDate': end_dt.strftime(date_format)}],
                'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:uniquePageviews'}, {'expression': 'ga:pageviews'},
                            {'expression': 'ga:timeOnPage'}, ],
                "dimensions": [{"name": "ga:pagePathLevel2"}],
                "dimensionFilterClauses": [
                    {
                        "filters": ...
                    }
                ]

            }]
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to match the IDs in `ga:pagePathLevel2`.

So, here is how the value of `filters` should look like.

```
[
    {
        "dimensionName": "ga:pagePathLevel2",
        "operator": "REGEXP",
        "expressions": ["23692|23693|23964|23965|23966"]
    }
]
```

Hope it helps !